# How to parse json string in contract?

Tags: smart-contract

My contract want to receive transfer with memo in json format, is there any libraries supporting the json parse?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in json-parser in the libs provided by eosio.cdt but you could include one of the several lightweight json-libraries yourself.

I would advise against it because it's probably very CPU-intensive (and RAM-intensive to include such a lib) and you should see if you can find another, more useful way.

You can for example see here how Eos-Knights goes about it: [Eos-Knights eosiotoken_transfer](https://github.com/bada-studio/knights_contract/blob/master/knights/contract/system_control.hpp#L56)